# How to get a variable from the Angular controller to a view

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I have a controller that looks like this:

```
angular.module('my_app')
  .controller('QueryCtrl', ['$scope', 'Query', function ($scope, Query) {
      $scope.onSubmit = function() {
          var json = $.post('http://162.243.232.223:3000/api/query', { 'input': 'my_input' });
          console.log(json);
          $scope.queries = json;
        };
      }
   ])
```

And a view that looks like this:

```
<div ng-controller="QueryCtrl">

  <form ng-submit="onSubmit()" >
    <textarea ng-model="query_box" name="my_input"></textarea>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>
  {{ queries }}
  <ul ng-repeat="query in queries">
    <li>{{query}}</li>
  </ul>

</div>
```

The problem is that, when I click the submit button, the javascript console successfully logs the correct json object, which has a property

```
responseJSON
```

You can take a closer look at the object I want by looking typing

```
$.post('http://162.243.232.223:3000/api/query', { 'input': 'my_input' });
```

into the javascript console yourself and checking out the object.

However, in the view, when I print out the "queries" object, it appears to not have a responseJSON attribute, but only a readyState attribute.

Where is the rest of my json object?

Comment: Any reason you aren't using the built in angular $http service?

Comment: first of all, you might as well use angular's version of Ajax; $http. in your case $http.post(...); Second, you should assign the response after the ajax call resolves (success, failure, complete); then show that in your html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
$scope.onSubmit = function() {
      var json = $.post('http://162.243.232.223:3000/api/query', { 'input': 'my_input' });
      json.done(function(result){
         $scope.result = result;
         $scope.$apply();
      })

      console.log(json);
      $scope.queries = json;
    };
  }

<div>{{result}}</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 var projectangular.module('my_app')
  .controller('QueryCtrl', ['$scope', 'Query', function ($scope,$http, Query) {
      $scope.onSubmit = function() {
          $http.post('http://162.243.232.223:3000/api/query', { 'input': 'my_input' }).then(

            //sucess
            function(response){

           angular.copy(response ,$scope.queries);
           console.log(json);

            },
            //error
            function(){
              alert("cant post");

            });

        };
      }
   ])
```

Answer (score 1):

As CAT commented, what you got back from .post is a promise object. You will have to wait for post request to complete (fail or succeed). Following syntax may be little off. I just typed it on the fly.

```
angular.module('my_app').controller('QueryCtrl', ['$scope', 'Query', function ($scope, Query) {
    $scope.onSubmit = function() {
        var json = $.post('http://162.243.232.223:3000/api/query', { 'input': 'my_input' }).then(function(response){
            console.log(response.data);
            $scope.queries = response.data;
            $scope.$apply();
        }, function(response){
            console.log(response.data);
            $scope.queries = response.data;
            $scope.$apply();
        });
    };
}])
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because of the promise system and how the objects are printed in the console, they are printed by reference and not by value. Try doing console.log(JSON.stringify(json)) which is a string and not an object and you will see that you are missing the the responseJSON attribute. you responseJSON attribute is probably attached to the object at a future time but the console.log(Object) will print it's current value, even tho that value was added after you used console.log.